# SQL join rows in two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm not good at SQL and wonder if this can be done: I have two tables: table_a and table_b. Both tables have a TEXT type column named category.

Example:

Table_a

```
|-id-|-category-|
| 1  | fruits   |
| 2  | meats    |
| 3  | fruits   |
| 4  | sweets   |
| 5  | meats    |
```

Table_b

```
|-id-|-category-|
| 1  | veggies  |
| 2  | meats    |
| 3  | veggies  |
| 4  | veggies  |
| 5  | meats    |
```

What I need is to select all distinct categories from both tables in alphabetic order.

The result should be:

```
fruits
meats
sweets
veggies
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't need to `join`, you need to `union`.

Comment: See my code, only `union` is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `UNION` and an `ORDER BY` clause :

```
SELECT DISTINCT category 
FROM Table_A
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT category
FROM Table_B
ORDER BY category
```

Comment: The DISTINCT is superfluous because of the UNION.

Comment: No its not, it will not discard duplicates if they are on the same table. @CL.

Answer (score 1):

In sql you could use union  and order by

```
 select distinct category from (
 select category 
 from table_a
 order by category
 union 
 select category 
 from table_b )
```

Comment: I have update the answer (strage becaus in slq union should be distinct but anyway

Comment: comment explain well the real motif because in sql shoul't necessary disticnt but anyway ..

Comment: If you wrapped it with another select, you should use `UNION ALL` for better performances.